# How to save associations with ActiveRecord Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi everyone i started to work in a rails application.
I have a problem with the associations, i have this:
A table User, a table Task and a table Type, the relationship between the tables is:
A User has many Taks and the Tasks have a particular Type.

In my controller user_controller.rb when i´m going create a new Task i have the following:

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params) #Working
  @user = User.find(5) #this is for a while
  @type = Type.find(params[:type_id]) #Working
  @task = @type.tasks.create(task_params) #this line saves the Task with the asociated Type
  @task = @user.tasks.create(task_params) #this line saves the Task with the asociated User
  #But the two lines together doesn't work
  #Con las validaciones puestan en el model se debe validar el retorno del metodo save
  if @task.save
    redirect_to @task
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**EDIT :** The 2 lines doesn't work together because only save the association with the User (second line) maybe because the second line calls the save method with the recent `@user.task.create(...)` if the second line is commented, then the first line saves only the Type association (obviously). I want save the 2 associations, not one of two :)
Task model

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Type model

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  validates :nombre, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
  validates :desc, presence: true
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :perfil
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
end
```

How can i save correctly the Task with the User and the Type associated? Thanks!

Comment: please explain "But the two lines together doesn't work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `tasks.create(task_params)` you're actually creating a new task for both the type and the user. Instead, you just want to set the associations like this:

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  @user = User.find(5)
  @type = Type.find(params[:type_id])
  @task.user = @user # Just set the reference!
  @task.type = @type # Just set the reference!

  if @task.save
    redirect_to @task
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both User and Type have the relation 'has_many :tasks', they each have a tasks[] array associated with them. That being the case, you could do something like the following:

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  @user = User.find(5)
  @type = Type.find(params[:type_id])
  @type.tasks << @task
  @user.tasks << @task

  if @user.save && @type.save
    redirect_to @task
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Saving @user and @type will automatically save the tasks associated with them, if they aren't already saved.